# How can i get image's rotation angle value

Tags: html, image, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to get **27** as a text from

```
 ` transform:rotate(27deg)`
```

```html
<div class="anlik-ruzgar-ikon"><img class="imgPR" ng-src="../Images_Sys/main_page/ryon-gri.svg" ng-style="{'transform': 'rotate('+sondurum[0].ruzgarYon+'deg)'}" src="../Images_Sys/main_page/ryon-gri.svg" style="transform: rotate(27deg);">       </div>
```

my current code is `soup.find('img', class_= 'imgPR')` and when i run, code shows all the `img class`. what add next to get 27.

Comment: You can use regular expressions. See for example: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regular-expressions-data-scientists/

Comment: sorry i am new at programing. thank you ,that might be works. i gonna try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next example how to locate right tag and parse the number from `style=` attribute:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="anlik-ruzgar-ikon"><img class="imgPR" ng-src="../Images_Sys/main_page/ryon-gri.svg" ng-style="{'transform': 'rotate('+sondurum[0].ruzgarYon+'deg)'}" src="../Images_Sys/main_page/ryon-gri.svg" style="transform: rotate(27deg);">       </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# locate right tag:
img = soup.select_one(".imgPR")

# get style property:
style = img["style"]

# parse the number from there:
deg = re.search(r"(\d+)deg", style).group(1)

print(deg)
```

Prints:

```
27
```